Why does Elias's product code have vanishing error rate?
I am studying information theory and I just encountered a code constructed by Elias in 1954. I am struglling to understand why this code gives vanishing error rate, as is shown also in this lecture note.
Specifically, my confusion lies in the following points:
From my understanding, Elias's code is a product code of $(2^m, 2^m-m, 4)$ extended Hamming codes. Let's denote extended Hamming codes as $C_m$. The code is defined as $C=\bigotimes_{m=r}^{r+n} C_m$. Thus, $C$ has a minimum distance of $d=4^n$ and should theoretically be able to correct up to $\lfloor(d-1)/2\rfloor = \lfloor 4^n/2\rfloor$ errors in a codeword using minimum distance decoding. Here, I assume computational complexity is not a concern. However, as the code length is $2^{O(n^2)}$, a typical codeword will have $p2^{O(n^2)}$ errors if the error probability of the binary symmetric channel is $p$. This typical number of errors far exceeds the correctable errors ($O(4^n)$), suggesting that the code should not have a vanishing decoding error probability.
Yet, both the lecture notes and the original paper claim that the code does achieve a vanishing error probability via sequential decoding. I cannot find any faults in their derivations, so now I am confused.
